# Dynamically check if the checkbox is checked on-fly

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div tag which contains a `series of checkboxes`. I would like to know whether one of the them is checked or not.

```
<div id="doctor" class="doctor">
   Doctor
   <input type="checkbox" id="doctor0" name="I am 22" value="I am 22">
   <label for="I am 22">I am 22</label><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="doctor1" name="I have a cough" value="I have a cough">
   <label for="I have a cough">I have a cough</label>
</div>

 <div id="patient" class="patient">
   Patient
   <input type="checkbox" id="patient0" name="I am Patient" value="I am patient">
   <label for="I am patient">I am patient</label><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="patient1" name="I have a cough" value="I have a cough">
   <label for="I have a cough">I have a cough</label>
</div>
```

I have these two div tags which contain a series of a dynamically generated checkbox. I would like to get if either one of these is checked or both of them is checked.

1. Check if one item or more item is checked under Doctor.
2. Check if one item or more item is checked under patient.

If both are true, do something. 
If only one of the item is checked, do something.

Code:

```
function getItem(event) {
  console.log(event.target.checked)
}
```

I am able to get whether its checked or not, but not sure how the particular item is checked or not. I don't want to manually access the dom elements.

```
if(document.getElementById("doctor0").checked || document.getElementById("patient0").checked)
```

Comment: You can use a selector with the result coerced to boolean like `!!document.querySelector('#doctor > input[type=checkbox]:checked')`. Returns true if one or more of the checkbox descendants of #doctor are checked, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` function to get list of checked checkbox in specific div.

If size of `list > 0`, it contains checked checkbox.

1. Check if one item or more item is checked under Doctor.

   `document.querySelectorAll('#doctor input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0`
2. Check if one item or more item is checked under patient.

   `document.querySelectorAll('#patient input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function in which you pass the id of a div `doctor/patient` that you want to select checkboxes from and concat this with checkbox selector.

With this you can re-use the same selector logic in both cases.

You can iterate trough HTMLNodeObject that is returned by `querySelectorAll` like you would normal array. Checkbox will have `.checked` -property which tells if it is selected or not.

```
function checkboxStatus(id) {
  let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} input[type="checkbox"]`);
  checkboxes.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.checked);
  });
}
```

[CodeSandbox -example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-resonance-i15lq)